# How do I pass a value to a widget if its already been initialized in an indexedstack?

Tags: flutter

I have  a widget that builds and indexedstack with (2) widgets. One first widget has a list of names, and when you tap a name, the indexedstack index number changes and it changes the page showing the second widget. I want to pass that name value to the second widget. The problem is that my main widget uses an indexedstack because I need the bottomnavigation bar. If I was to use navigator I could modify my widgets constructor but then that would make the whole page reload, which is why I am using a indexedstack so the body pages change the bottomnavigation bar remains the same.

Comment: *"The problem is that my main widget uses an indexedstack"* - and what is the problem with that `IndexedStack`?

Comment: @pskink im facing a problem that I cant pass a value to the 2nd widget in the indexed stack because the value is generated in the first widget of the indexedstack. The main widget by default shows the first widget in the indexedstack. I tap a name from the list in the first widget of the indexedstack and I want that name value to be passed to the 2nd widget in the indexedstack. If I used navigator + 2nd widget's constructor I can easily do this but I am just changing screens by changing the value of the index for the indexedstack.

Comment: so you need to rebuild `IndexedStack` - it does not have any "listenaable" property that you could use at runtime

Comment: @pskink rebuild IndexedStack meaning trigger the rebuild method in the widget to rebuild the IndexedStack widget? How does this help with passing a value to the 2nd widget in the IndexedSTack?

Comment: by doing so you can build your `IndexedStack` and all its children from scratch passing whatever values you want